# Find duplicate object based on value property in array of objects and then reduce the array concatenating the duplicate object in its label property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Suppose I have an array of objects like this:

```json
[ 
    {value: "2021", label: "REDS"},
    {value: "2020", label: "REDS"},
    {value: "2021", label: "COPASA"},
    {value: "2021", label: "CEMIG_CLIENTES"},
    {value: "2016", label: "CEMIG_CLIENTES"},
    {value: "2016", label: "RFQSA"}
]
```

What I need is to find the duplicate entries based on the value property and output a new array concatenating its label property. So the result would be something like this:

```json
[ 
    {value: "2021", label: "REDS/COPASA/CEMIG_CLIENTES"},
    {value: "2020", label: "REDS"},
    {value: "2016", label: "CEMIG_CLIENTES/RFQSA"}
]
```

How can I achieve this? I am stuck.
I have tried getting the unique values and achieved it with this:

```
 const unique =  arr.map(e => e['value'])
             .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)
             .filter(obj=> aux2[obj])
             .map(e => aux2[e]);
```

However it won't be enough because the labels cannot be lost, I also thought about ordering the array and running a function to get the positions of the duplicates to then pop out the next occurences by merging them together. But I have not been able to achieve it yet.
Is there a better way? If not, can anyone shed some light on how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First off, your first object seems to be invalid because of unbalanced quotes on the last line. Secondly, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have created a function that returns the new array with no duplicates, but then I lost the labels of the duplicates which cannot happen.
Thanks for pointing out the unbalanced quotes, it's fixed.

Comment: Ahahaha incredible, I need the exact same thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved with a for loop. Loop over the objects, construct a new array, check if value already exists and if it does concatenate the label, otherwise add a new entry:

```js
function removeDuplicates(arr) {
  const newArr = [];

  for (const obj of arr) {
    const existing = newArr.find((el) => el.value === obj.value);
    if (existing) {
      existing.label += "/" + obj.label;
    } else {
      newArr.push(obj);
    }
  }
  
  return newArr;
}

console.log(removeDuplicates([ 
  {value: "2021", label: "REDS"},
  {value: "2020", label: "REDS"},
  {value: "2021", label: "COPASA"},
  {value: "2021", label: "CEMIG_CLIENTES"},
  {value: "2016", label: "CEMIG_CLIENTES"},
  {value: "2016", label: "RFQSA"}
]));
```

If performance matters, that could be sped up using an object for newArr and the value for the key, then you don't need to do a `.find` every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function combineSimilar (arr) {
    const map = {};
    arr.forEach(x => {
        if (!map[x.value]) {
            map[x.value] = x;
        }
        else {
            map[x.value].label += "/" + x.label;
        }
    });

    return Object.values(map);
}

console.log(combineSimilar([ 
    {value: "2021", label: "REDS"},
    {value: "2020", label: "REDS"},
    {value: "2021", label: "COPASA"},
    {value: "2021", label: "CEMIG_CLIENTES"},
    {value: "2016", label: "CEMIG_CLIENTES"},
    {value: "2016", label: "RFQSA"}
]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone needs this solution, here's a **generic** version inspired from Giorgi Moniava's reply.
I made the code more compact, and you can choose your key to find duplicates, then pass a combine callback, to determine how values are merged.
In my case I want to join duped values with a pipe (see usage below).

```js
function combineDupes(arr, dupeKey, combineFn) {
    return Object.values(
        arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
            const uid = item[dupeKey];
            acc[uid] = acc[uid] ? combineFn(acc[uid], item) : item;

            return acc;
        }, {})
    );
}
```

usage

```
combineSimilar(myArr, "dupeKey", (target, dupe) => {
            
    return {
        ...target,
        foo: [target.foo, dupe.foo].join("|") 
    };
});
```